# How to get node.js/socket.IO server work with cloudflare?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudflare

I have a node.js/socket.IO server that has been under attack recently, so I decided to start using cloudflare to hide my server IP. However, anyone can easily get the server IP from the client javascript file. Is there anything I can do to connect through cloudflare and not my server directly, so I can help prevent attackers from getting the server IP?

E.g.:

```
var client = io.connect('http://141.101.xxx.xxx:466');
```

That would be the IP when I ping the domain that is using cloudflare. I try to connect to it directly.

Even attempting to connect to the domain itself doesn't seem to work

```
var client = io.connect('http://mydomainthatusescloudflare.com:466');
```

Only thing that works is directly connecting to the server, without going through cloudflare (thus revealing the IP)

```
var client = io.connect('http://217.xxx.xxx.xxx:466');
```

Comment: Connecting to the cloudflare domain won't work, since they don't forward the ports to your server. This problem shouldn't be solved through obscurity, but rather, a load balancer or something of the sort. You could also just create a subdomain and point it to your origin server, but the IP could still be figured out.

Comment: @rob Any recommendations to some that can prevent average DDoS attacks?

Comment: Scale based on traffic, I don't know of any specific drop-in solution, have you tried doing a search on it? It all depends on the kind of service, budget and infrastructure you want to manage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cfdomain:80` for socket.io and add this line,

```
io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling", "jsonp-polling"]);
```

but disconnected event isnt work. I am trying to fix it.

Comment: Please tell me when you find a fix for it!